# R ggplot bar graph with color filled, how to normalized each column to percentage?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar graph with color filled plotting like this,

```
ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x=factor(cyl), fill=factor(vs))+geom_bar()
```

[image]

How to transform each column to percentage? something like the following?

Any hint is appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: it's bar graph you have!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: try `position="fill"` : `ggplot(mtcars) + aes(x=factor(cyl), fill=factor(vs))+geom_bar(position="fill")`